# Create a function to evaluate if all elements in the array are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

#### Problem

I'm trying to create a function that evaluates an array and if every element inside the array is the same, it would return **true** and otherwise **false**. I don't want it to return **true/false** for each individual element, just for the entire array.

#### Attempt 1

This method works, but it returns **true/false** for each element in the array:

```
function isUniform(arr){
    let first = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i <arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[0] !== arr[i]){
            console.log(false);
        } else {
            console.log(true);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Attempt 2

This method returns **true/false**, once and then prints true again at the end:

```
function isUniform(arr){
    let first = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i <arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[0] !== arr[i]){
            console.log(false);
        }
    }
    console.log(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test if something is true for every element of an array, you don't really need to write much — you can use [`array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for this and just compare the first element. `every()` is nice because it will return early if a false condition is found.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
var arr2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]

console.log(arr1.every((n, _, self) => n === self[0]))
console.log(arr2.every((n, _, self) => n === self[0]))
```

This will return true for an empty array, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, this is a different approach, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz the OP is asking for if all the elements in the array are the same or not

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep this in mind in the future - right now I'm restricted to just using a for loop or for each, but I'm glad I learned this.

Comment: if only the question is to check, then is clearly a duplicate question and a matter of a close request.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using the object `Set`

```
new Set(arr).size === 1 // This means all the elements are equal.
```

```js
let isUniform = (arr) => new Set(arr).size === 1;

console.log(isUniform([4,4,4,4,4]));
console.log(isUniform([4,4,4,4,4,5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) with `false` and end the function. The return value could be used later.

```
function isUniform(arr) {
    let first = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[0] !== arr[i]) {
            console.log(false);
            return false;
        }
    }
    console.log(true);
    return true;
}
```

For using a return value, you need to return `true` at the end, too.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Ugh, it's always something stupidly obvious and simple like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) .its Checking all other value is same with  first index of array

```js
function isUniform(arr) {
  return arr.every(a=> a === arr[0])
}

console.log(isUniform([2,2,2,2]));
console.log(isUniform([4,4,4,4,4,5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to stop once you've found the first false element:

```
function isUniform(arr){
    let first = arr[0]; 
    let uniform = true;
    for (let i = 1; i <arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[0] !== arr[i]){
            uniform = false; 
            break;
        }
    } 
    console.log(uniform);
}
```

Comment: `break` does not prevent to show `true`. it just exits the loop.